# Клиент-серверное приложение на Си и энергоэффективность

Tags: linux, c, энергосбережение

Есть простейшее клиент-серверное приложение, скажем сервер раз в час шлет клиенту стандартное сообщение "Привет". Клиенту нужно просто получить сообщение и вывести его на экран. Как добиться максимального энергосбережения на клиенте (например это телефон). ОС -linux. Т.е. нужно чтобы сеть работала минимально. Имеет ли значение что использовать poll / select/ или просто блокирующий вызов recv?

Comment: Если сервер в любой момент может прислать "Привет" как сеть сможет минимально работать? Ей придется все время работать. Либо, если не критично, включаться раз в 10 минут, но тогда будет задержка соответственно.

Comment: приложение может спать любым из этих способов. ядро не будет давать ему управление, пока не появятся данные в сокете. и следовательно приложение не будет потреблять процессор и энергию. А ядру в принципе то же все равно, все эти ожидания просто записи в соответствующих таблицах, их обслуживание в холостом режиме не требуется

Comment: Благодарю за полезный коммент. Еще уточню, на всякий случай: а как ядро примет данные в сокет, придется включать сеть, если включать то как часто, или это все заботы ядра и то что в ожидании висит poll на это не влияет?

Comment: Уточню, то не понятно, имеет ли смысл приложению, как сказано в 1ом комменте, засыпать и просыпаться с определенной периодичностью или нет?

Comment: IMHO, ушли в какую-то микрооптимизацию. Кто-то что-то профилировал? Почему "сеть работала минимально" вообще влияет на работу конкретного устройства? "Например, это телефон" - какой телефон? Вы хотите стать умней андроида/ios?